# Temporary table at runtime

Tags: axapta, x++

Is it possible to set table as temporary table at run time in ax 2009?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mark a record buffer as temporary using the `setTmp` method. Also remember to call the `doInsert` method instead of the `insert` method if you want to avoid the any other updates made in the `insert` method.

To have a second record buffer refer to the same temporary table use the `setTmpData` method.

This test job illustrates the use:

```
static void TmpTest(Args _args)
{
    CustTable custTable, custTable2;
    ;
    custTable.setTmp();
    custTable.AccountNum = "123Tmp";
    custTable.Name = "Temporary?";
    custTable.doInsert();

    custTable2.setTmp();
    custTable2.setTmpData(custTable);
    select custTable2 where custTable2.AccountNum == "123Tmp";
    info(custTable2.Name);
}
```

Comment: Using the `skipDataMethods` method does not work on `insert` only on `insert_recordset`.